# Intellij file class path

Tags: file-io, intellij-idea, classpath

In Intellij, I have the file located in class path resources folder and the folder is marked as resources also.
But, still when I use:

```
new FileInputStream("myFile.xml");
```

I am getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myFile.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your myFile.xml is in resources folder
Try reading like this

```
    InputStream inputStream = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/myFile.xml");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```